# Ajax Call going to Error Block

Tags: jquery, ajax

Please find the code below:

I am trying to make an AJAX call which reads the json content in a json file from Server. I am alerting the URL and if i hit the URL i am getting the JSON content. But if i do an AJAX call i am getting an Error while doing the call. Not Sure why is it going to Error Block. Can anybody please suggest?

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<script type="text/javascript">

var arrForG = ["1"];
var arrForS = ["Test1"];
var arrForSt = ["VT"];
var edgateurl;
var obj;


$.each(arrForSt, function (i, itemI) {
    $.each(arrForG, function (j, itemJ) {
        $.each(arrForS, function (k, itemK) {
            url1 = itemI+"-"+itemJ+"-"+itemK.split(' ').join('')+".json";
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: url1 ,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data){
                    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                },
                error: function(data){
                    alert("Error:" + data);
                },
                complete: function (response) {
                  //alert(JSON.stringify(response));
                 }
            }); 
        })
    })
})

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: What response code do you get on the request? Is it 500? 404? 401? Any responseText in the returned data object?

Comment: I got it resolved. there is a "www." in the link. That shouldnt be there in my case. Thanks a lot for the response. @GuyPassy